# How to change the code from Scala to Python

Tags: python, scala

```scala
def computeTotalVariationDistance(p: Distribution, q: Distribution): Double = {
    val pSum = p.sum
    val qSum = q.sum
    val l1Distance = p.zip(q)
      .map { case (_, pVal, qVal) =>
        math.abs((pVal / pSum) - (qVal / qSum))
      }
      .sum

    0.5 * l1Distance
  }
```

Can someone help me to change this code into python.

Comment: What are you struggling with?

Comment: I am struggling with the map part. I am not able to iterate over float and sum it value

Answer (score 0):

It's actually relatively straightforward. Instead of map, you can use list comprehension:

```
l1Distance = sum(
             [abs((pVal / pSum) - (qVal / qSum)) 
              for pVal, qVal in zip(p, q)]
             )
```

I have not tested this but it should work, or something very similar.

Comment: Its returning me a list of float, not the sum.

Comment: @uditi Pretty sure you can figure out how to sum a list of values.

Comment: the problem i am facing is how to convert float into list

Comment: @uditi I don't get it, p and q are vectors, right? So lists of floats? Then zip(p, q) is also a list (of float pairs). That list comprehension makes a list of floats then, and the sum should be summing the values in that list. Where is the data type not fitting?

Comment: new=[[i] for i in l1Distance] this gives me the error: 'float' object is not iterable . p = [13,13,14,15] , q = [23,12,12,14]

Comment: @uditi l1Distance is a single number. If you want that in a list, then just do `[l1Distance]`

Comment: [l1Distance] = abs((p_value / pSum) - (q_value / qSum))
       for i in l1Distance:
         print(i)  this gives the me the error cannot unpack non-iterable float object

Comment: @uditi `def computeTotalVariationDistance(p: Distribution, q: Distribution): Double` the output of that function is supposed to be a single number, right?

Comment: yes, the output is supposed to be a single number. I have to do a sum and then multiply it with 0.5

Comment: I resolved it by doing something like l1Distances.append(abs((p_value/pSum)-(q_value/qSum)))